# Install Postgres10.1 on Centos 7

Tags: postgresql

It is possible to install PostgresSQL 10.6 on any Red Hat flavour Linux but it seems like I am not able to install a specific version namely 10.1. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: The current minor release of Postgres 10 is 10.6, the Postgres [yum repository](https://yum.postgresql.org/) only has the latest (minor) version. Why would you want to install an old version that is known to contain bugs?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name we want it to be the same environment as the previous environment

Comment: It makes no sense to install a minor version that has been superseded with 5 bugfix releases. The "previous environment" shouldn't have used that version either. [Quote from the homepage](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/): "*For minor releases, the community considers not upgrading to be riskier than upgrading*"